# Is making [icarus] a synonym for [iverilog] the best approach?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

The [iverilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iverilog) and [icarus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/icarus) tags are really the same; they are both used for [Icarus Verilog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icarus_Verilog),
which is the name of the open-source Verilog simulation software.  `icarus` is the informal name of the software, and `iverilog` is the name of the command to run the simulation software.  I don't understand why 2 tags exist.

We're not talking about a lot of questions: `iverilog` has about 100 and `icarus` about 50.

`iverilog` has more complete tag info and there are
more questions, which means people think of using `iverilog` more often than `icarus`.

I see that `iverilog` has `icarus` as a suggested synonym.
Ideally, there would only be one tag.  Can these tags be merged so that we only end up with one?
Or, should I make `icarus` a synonym for `iverilog`?  What is the best approach?

Comment: I think that we should rename both to [icaus-verilog] and be done with it. Like other products that are known for its maker and product name.

Comment: I agree that they should be synonyms.  Most people will know `iverilog` as it is the command line name.  I believe it is possible to retag the 65 icarus question to iverilog manually or you can wait for people to get enough reputation to approve the synonym.  The issue with this is that knowledgeable people will ignore one or the other; for instance not visit the icarus tag.  You can also edit the tag to say, prefer iverilog instead (or whatever you think).

Comment: Also [modelsim] and [questasim].  36 questions with both tags.  They are different programs (versions) with significant differences underneath, but present the same sort of interface to a user.